# How do people locate regedit entries so precisely to change or affect options in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-registry, regedit

I had an issue after running a battery test through cmd on Windows which

**Resulted in:**

> The device or driver has made a request to prevent the system from
>   automatically entering sleep. Driver Name \FileSystem\rdbss

So, I decided to go see what that was and I found an answer suggestion to the issue.[This post that seems to suggest making a registry edit to allow sleep with remote files open](http://thegreenbutton.com/forums/t/75159.aspx?PageIndex=2) will solve the problem.

**From the post:**

> *to show the hidden power property that can allow a system to sleep
>   whilst network shares are open You can either set this via the Group
>   Policy Editor (gpedit.msc), or you can enable it to appear in Power
>   Properties by opening Regedit and going to:
>   `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\ Control\ Power\PowerSettings\
>   238C9FA8-0AAD-41ED-83F4-97BE242C8F20\d4c1d4c8-d5cc-43d3-b83e-fc51215cb04d]`
>   In there, set Attributes to 0 (the default value is 1, which means
>   hide).*

I found this answer [here on answers.microsoft.com](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/wont-sleep-automatically-with-network-files-open/cbe07092-53b0-40aa-89a4-fc390d4e48a1?auth=1).

My question is HOW in the world do people find such deep locations in the Windows registry to make such a change?  Is there some kind of App that analyzes and located the registry entry being used?  No human can do or remember these paths, so there must be a way to parse the registry for the data.

Comment: one way is to "watch" the registry using a program that notices changes to it, and test changing the configuration. In other cases they may know that the CLSID for a given component is `238C9FA8-0AAD-41ED-83F4-97BE242C8F20`, so they search for it and poke around. Or mabey they had a support call with MS to fix a specific problem and then shared that information online.

Comment: How: Experience.  Battery problem points to Power, logically, you start looking at the PowerSettings for the device, knowing what attributes for that given key does is just experience.  There are also entire volumes of books that help you gain this experience. More importantly what registry keys are set by what grouppolicy is well documented.

Comment: You do realize that Registry Editor has a search function that can cover the entire registry?

Comment: I use reg shot to do comparisons to find out what keys are being changed, some people have been working in the registry for so many years they can make educated guesses where most settings are....  http://www.howtogeek.com/198679/how-to-use-regshot-to-monitor-your-registry/

Comment: **HOW in the world do people find such deep locations in the Windows registry to make such a change?**. . . .  Using the good old fashioned cross your fingers, guess, and pick something technique... Not!! just joking, but usually with research, research, some reading, and more research unless you remember and have worked a problem so much you remember it but you have to learn it with research or someone showing you or trial and error for the most part when troubleshooting a problem to find what registry key may need adjusted, etc. to resolve.

Comment: In addition to what others are saying, in the case of Group Policy (or GPO) settings, you can search through the ADM/ADMX/ADML files that define the available GPO settings. These files contain the human-friendly setting names and descriptions that you see in the editor, and they also contain the actual registry key paths and value names that correspond to the settings, plus the "legal" values that can be used for that setting.

Comment: Registry searching would not have found this option since I have no idea what to search for. RegShot seems very interesting to be able to tell what is in the process of changing, but in this case it wouldn't have helped since the reg setting is something inherent in our Windows installations. May be a MS person did tell them where the reg entry was.   Thanks for the format fix PIMP, I still don't know how to do it properly.

Comment: To track realtime changes made to the registry, Process Monitor is what you need. [How to Use Process Monitor to Track Registry and File System Changes](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/process-monitor-track-events-generate-log-file/)

Answer (score 1):

It's just something you learn over time and with a lot of experience.  It's a familiarity thing.

The registry is just the central place where settings are stored.  ANY program can read from or write to it.  Many of the values it contains are only meaningful to the application that created them.  Some are very well documented, and some are very poorly documented or not at all.  If you work with the registry a lot, you get to know where certain things are supposed to be, and which branches of the tree do different things.  Once you know that, you have an idea of where to start looking when things go wrong.

You often just flex your Google-Fu and find the error/behavior/similar problem, figure out what component *could* be causing it, Google that, form a hypothesis, Google some more...  If you're lucky, you land on some obscure document somewhere that explains what you're looking for or how things work.  Failing that, you just experiment using whatever knowledge you've gained along your journey.

If you do this enough times, and blow up a few computers along the way, you gain a deeper understanding of the relationship between what components do what things, and where those things are recorded in the registry.  Not everyone is up to the task.  Sometimes it just takes brute-force trial-and-error, or long hours of comparing the state of one machine to another, changing a setting, and seeing what happens.

I suppose what I'm trying to say is that there is no manual that spells everything out for you.  The registry is a complex beast and it just takes years of practice to be good enough to just zip right to the spot that's giving you trouble.  Even then, there's still a lot of guesswork and hunches involved.

Comment: Someone above mentioned getting the info from a MS tech call or using Regshot as well:

http://www.howtogeek.com/198679/how-to-use-regshot-to-monitor-your-registry/

Thanks for letting me know I'm not nuts though.

Answer (score 0):

if searching the net (or asking here) doesn't produce a solution there are generally 2 approaches.

1. blackbox testing:
   you have no idea whats going on in the process, so you make a snapshot of whatever goes into the 'machine' and make another snapshot of what comes out of it.
   meaning, like in the comments suggested, use a tool like regshot.
   you make a snapshot of the registry, change some config using the UI and then do a snapshot again. compare the results and theoretically you can see it then.
2. whitebox testing
   make some change to the configuration and monitor directly what is happening.
   a good tool for this would be procmon.

both require that you filter the results (a lot), because the registry is used for much more than just that one configuration you changed.
this is where experience helps a lot.

you can verify that you have the right key by changing it and see if it has an effect.

i'm not sure if this is the answer you seek.
because in your specific example you mention a group policy.
they are well documented and i'm sure there is an easy technique to find the regkeys resulting in setting a group policy.
but this will better be answered by some experienced windows admin :)